# Memory Leak in Instruments

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

```
NSString *toDateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

`100% Memory` `Leak` on above line in instrument.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you retaining `toDateTimeString` at some point? Instruments tells you where a leak was allocated, but that doesn't necessarily tell you the real reason for the leak. As far as we can tell from the code you posted, you're not responsible for releasing `toDateTimeString`. Refer to [the memory management rules](http://tinyurl.com/6ktdglb). However, if have a subsequent line like:

```
[toDateTimeString retain];
```

without a matching release, that would account for the leak. If that's the case, then the other two responses are correct and you should release (or autorelease) `toDateTimeString` before the end of the method. Or, better, just remove the retain. The string you get back from -stringFromDate: will be valid through the end of your method, so there's no need to retain it again.

Comment: Instruments does let you examine the entire history of the leaked object (or any other), from which you can determine what retained it that should have released it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:  The code in question runs in an environment where it doesn't ever purge the autorelease pool.  Perhaps you are running this code in a background thread that doesn't declare an autorelease pool upon entry?

Comment: A quick way to determine if that's the case (just in case you're not sure if you're using threads ;-) is to look for an error in the console. [The docs](http://tinyurl.com/5wbwvzr) say that Cocoa will log an error if you send -autorelease when there's no autorelease pool.

Comment: Good to know.  Sometimes it's not obvious that you are in a different thread.  Using Audio Unit callbacks, for instance.

Answer (score -3):

You could release the toDateTimeString, but it would be better to initialize it like this:

```
NSString *toDateTimeString = [NSString stringWithString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

As the documentation says, it **Returns a string created by copying the characters from another given string.**

Comment: If -stringFromDate: is leaking, copying the leaked string isn't going to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense. You've replaced one non-owned object with another non-owned object and claimed that it will somehow make the memory go away.

Comment: Why would that be “better” at all? All it does is create a redundant copy of the string that is being leaked. (And then, as BJ says, the copy would be leaked instead of the original. But that's still a leak.)

Comment: Who said it is leaking stringFromDate??? its said that it is leaking in that line of code. And my answer was from a what I supposed to be a memory leak. And as I know, memory leaks points where the object is initialized. In our case the initializes object is an NSString, so it is NSString which is leaking but not stringFromDate.

Comment: Anyway, how can you increase comment rate, if it is not a technically correct answer. I talk about @Caleb, actually in Objective-C objects a leaking memory, but not methods.

Comment: -stringFromDate is the method allocating the leaked object, and is thus said to be "leaking."